# Change settings of word repetition from TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm currently working on my bachelor thesis with texstudio. There is a tool integrated which is quite helpful for making improvements in my writing style. It is called "word repetition" and marks up words which are repeated within a small word distance. I want this tool to look up the a lager distance to improve my document but don't know where to find the advanced options.

Comment: The scope of the word repetition check is in terms of words, not sentences. Under `language` -> `internal grammar check`?

Comment: Yes you are right, can I maximize the distance of words?

Comment: What do you mean maximize? If you want to increase the scope of the check, then you can increase the `Words between repetition` and `Long range repetition` count. (default is 3 and 10 respectively, I think). Take note the `show advanced options` checkbox (bottom left of the options menu) must be checked.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english I meant how to increase them just as you said. Thanks I did not find the advanced options checkbox in the settings.

Comment: No worries, glad to help `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scope of the word repetition check is in terms of words, not sentences.

The settings for word repetition check is hidden behind the `Advanced Options`. In the `Configure TeXstudio` menu, check the bottom left box that says `Show Advanced Options`.

[image: options]

Under `Language -> Internal Grammar check`, you will find the options to increase/decrease the length of the scope of word repetition check.

You would want to increase the numbers for the first two boxes, in your case, I believe.

Comment: AVOID CHECKING VARIABLES by having there "0", "3", "2". Then you can write $n^n=...$ without TeXstudio nagging about the n's being too close to each other, or other 1-letter variables, as "Min Length ..." is "2" and no nagging for others ("0"). Formulae can be read much more easily while you work. When you want to publish your work, change the settings back for a final check.