# TexStudio: Is there a way to move from one highlighted word to the next highlighted word within a document

Tags: texstudio

In TexStudio, is there a way to move from one highlighted word (for e.g., a word highlighted in green due to word repetition) to the next highlighted word within a document?

For example, consider the following sentence:

The quick *quick* brown fox jumps over the *the* lazy dog.

What I am looking for is a keyboard shortcut (like F12) that, when pressed, takes me to the second occurrence of the word 'quick' and following that (when F12 is pressed again) to the second occurrence of the word 'the'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own shortcut for `Find Word Repetitions` see the following

[image]

If you wish to **change (expand) the scope of repetitions** then see Troy's answer here
 [Change settings of word repetition from TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396725/change-settings-of-word-repetition-from-texstudio)